# Mac OS X 10.6 clients cannot see ._resource fork files on a CIFS network share

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, network-shares, file-sharing

We have a Windows server, with Mac OS X 10.5 and 10.6 clients. On the server are some Automator workflows with custom icons stored in external resoruce fork files, like this:

```
foo.wflow
._foo.wflow
```

The custom icons are only visible to the 10.5 clients.

Answer (score 5):

As of 10.6, the Mac OS X CIFS/SMB client uses NTFS alternate data streams to store the resource fork instead of dot underscore AppleDouble files.

To turn NTFS Streams off in 10.6 create the file `/etc/nsmb.conf` if doesn’t already exist, and add the following lines:

```
[default]
streams=no
```

Or to turn it on in 10.5:

```
[default]
streams=yes
```

After changing this file, you will need to disconnect and reconnect your CIFS/SMB volumes.

Comment: With SMB, do 10.6 and later versions of the OS default to using NTFS ADS for *extended attributes*?